# Trying to move database entitites to another namespace but get error: IdentityDb' context has changed - AspnetUser is changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

Kinda stuck here. Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to move two database classes to another namespace :

```
    public class UserNotificationSubscription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employee")] public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int NotificationSubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NotificationSubscriptionId")]
    public virtual CustomerNotificationSubscription CustomerNotificationSubscription { get; set; }

    public bool IsInternalNotificationEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsExternalNotificationEnabled { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")] public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerNotificationSubscription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public NotificationEvent NotificationEvent { get; set; }

    public NotificationCategory NotificationCategory { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ChangedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChangedByEmployee")] public int? ChangedByEmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee ChangedByEmployee { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")] public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }


    public string EmployeesJson { get; set; }


    public IList<UserNotificationSubscription> UserNotificationSubscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

but when I move them, update references, build and try I get the "The model backing the 'IdentityDb' context has changed since the database was created." error. So I try to add a migration to see if anything's changed, and this migration is genereated:

```
    public partial class Test : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Password");
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Discriminator");
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Discriminator", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Password", c => c.String());
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Never seen that happened before. I've already moved a bunch of other classes with no problem, but these are the 2 I had left and then this happens. The new namespace is in another project called Domain. I even tried "faking" the namespace in the original project aka using the new namespace in the old cs file, and that also works fine. And then I tried commenting out the "old" cs file, and uncommenting the "new", and then it crashes again. I've tried using Resharper's built in move tool and that also makes it crash.

Comment: What version of ef?

Comment: I have
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.1.0 and
EntityFramework 6.1.2

Comment: Is this in production, or can you just delete and recreate your Migrations?

Comment: Yeah, this is in production. Been for several years. So I can't do that.

Comment: I did some more testing and it appears at least that it doesn't have anything to do with these specific classes. I tried moving them back so that I ended up with another remaining class. And when I moved that one to the new namespace, the same error happened.